# AWS Network Load Balancer access logs modification

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb, nlb

I am trying to get information about custom headers in the request to the network load balancer, in the access logs of the network load balancer. Is it possible to add custom fields to access logs?

Answer (score 1):

NLB does not capture information about headers, as this requires level 7 functionality. NLB is for **level 4 traffic** (TCP).

Appart from that, access [log format](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/network/load-balancer-access-logs.html#access-log-file-format) is **fixed**, and you can't modify it, unless done "manually" outside of NLB.

Comment: can I modify access logs by adding information about custom headers using a Application Loadbalancer

Comment: @VarunKS Sadly, you can't modify them.